# Is my regression with a factor variable doing what I think it is for Diff-in-Diff in R?

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, difference-in-difference, matching

I am running a difference-in-differences (DiD) regression on a data frame that looks something like this:

| lotnum | treatment | period | crimes | subclass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lot1 | 1 | 0 | 14 | 1 |
| lot1 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| lot3 | 0 | 0 | 16 | 1 |
| lot3 | 0 | 1 | 17 | 1 |
| lot5 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 1 |
| lot5 | 0 | 1 | 11 | 1 |
| lot2 | 1 | 0 | 20 | 2 |
| lot2 | 1 | 1 | 16 | 2 |
| lot3 | 0 | 0 | 16 | 2 |
| lot3 | 0 | 1 | 17 | 2 |
| lot9 | 0 | 0 | 19 | 2 |
| lot9 | 0 | 1 | 20 | 2 |

The reason I added the `subclass` column was to link control lots that have been matched to treated lots on the basis of being in the same area of a city but at least a certain distance away. As you can see, some control lots are matched to more than one treated lot. My goal is to run a regression such that only the matched control lots are used for each separate treated lot.

I ran something like this in R:

`summary(fit1 <- glm(crimes ~ factor(subclass)*(treatment*period), data = df, family = poisson))`

I get results for:
(Intercept)
factor(subclass)#
treatmentTRUE
periodTRUE
factor(subclass)#:treatmentTRUE
factor(subclass)#:periodTRUE

But what I am interested is the DiD term: `treatmentTRUE:periodTRUE`.

Is it correct to believe that R is doing the regression as I stated before? With only the control lots matched to each individual treated lot being used when determining the DiD term?

The other way I have run my regression is on a slightly different data frame which excludes subclasses and only contains one instance of each control lot. But I know this method would be running the DiD model on all treated lots and all control lots with no matching.

Edit:
summary output with subclass:

```
summary(fit1 <- glm(cps ~ factor(subclass)*(treated_group*is_post), data = df.match, family = poisson))
```

```
Coefficients:
                                                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                                        2.870331   0.025976 110.498  < 2e-16 ***
factor(subclass)2                                 -0.152802   0.038222  -3.998 6.39e-05 ***
factor(subclass)3                                  0.062766   0.036173   1.735 0.082713 .  
factor(subclass)4                                 -0.181512   0.038520  -4.712 2.45e-06 ***
......
factor(subclass)76                                 0.163935   0.035320   4.641 3.46e-06 ***
treated_groupTRUE                                 -1.771719   0.237129  -7.472 7.93e-14 ***
is_postTRUE                                       -0.226185   0.038997  -5.800 6.63e-09 ***
treated_groupTRUE:is_postTRUE                     -0.872428   0.473015  -1.844 0.065125 .  
factor(subclass)2:treated_groupTRUE                0.440484   0.314139   1.402 0.160857    
factor(subclass)3:treated_groupTRUE                1.834354   0.255338   7.184 6.77e-13 ***
factor(subclass)4:treated_groupTRUE                2.450196   0.250572   9.778  < 2e-16 ***
......
factor(subclass)75:treated_groupTRUE               0.799858   0.314679   2.542 0.011028 *  
factor(subclass)76:treated_groupTRUE               0.816894   0.278633   2.932 0.003370 ** 
factor(subclass)2:is_postTRUE                      0.073605   0.056769   1.297 0.194778    
factor(subclass)3:is_postTRUE                      0.281652   0.052479   5.367 8.01e-08 ***
factor(subclass)4:is_postTRUE                      0.176423   0.056393   3.128 0.001757 ** 
......
[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 104 rows ]
```

without the `subclass` variable

```
summary(fit2 <- glm(cps ~ treated_group*is_post, data = df.season, family = poisson))
```

```
Coefficients:
                               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                    2.841988   0.005819 488.394   <2e-16 ***
treated_groupTRUE             -0.301630   0.014379 -20.977   <2e-16 ***
is_postTRUE                   -0.182728   0.008632 -21.169   <2e-16 ***
treated_groupTRUE:is_postTRUE -0.051105   0.021583  -2.368   0.0179 *
```

In both, `cps` is measured as crime per park per season (May-Oct).

The difference between `df.season` and `df.match` is that the latter includes the `subclass` variable, which is matching the treated and control lots, and therefore includes some duplicate control lots with different subclasses that are matched to more than one treated lot.

Comment: The subclass variable is delineating different *city sections*. If the goal is to restrict candidate control lots to the same geographic section of the city (but not too close to avoid spillovers), how is 'lot3' in both sections? Also, please post your full summary output.

Comment: @ThomasBilach The subclass variable matches treated lots to control lots that are in the same district, but different neighborhoods. Treated lots in the same district may share control lots as each district has multiple neighborhoods. My full summary output is a bit long when I include the subclass in the regression, as it includes 75 instances for each of the factor(subclass)# I show listed.

Comment: For the lot matching, I made a list of every control lot that was in the same district but different neighborhood for each treated lot. Then 14 (the least amount matched to a single treated lot, some had as many as 64 matches) control lots were randomly chosen from each list to be matched with their respective treated lot. This is why some control lots are used multiple times.

Comment: In the "greening" literature, which this is closely tied to, evaluators may match the 'treated' to 'untreated' based upon certain criteria (e.g., lot size, median household income in the surrounding area, etc.). You could run one model for the whole city/district, or separate runs by city section. If you go with the former, then you end up with many duplicates. In your matching process did you remove duplicated lots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try and tackle each one of your concerns.

Suppose the city jurisdiction is split into four sections. In each section, a treated lot may be paired with multiple untreated lots. In the greening literature, the ratio of untreated to treated lots is usually around 4 to 1, though I've seen smaller ratios. Some use caliper matching to guarantee a particular ratio, but other methods exist. After matching it is reasonable to assume untreated lots would have been 'greened' around the same time as the treated lots.

To begin, suppose you run one big fat regression and ignored the geographic heterogeneity across city sections. Again, to do this you shouldn't have duplicate lots in the resulting data frame. Your model should look something like the following:

$$
\mathrm{log}(y_{it}) = \gamma T_{it} + \lambda P_{it} + \delta (T_{it} \times P_{it}) + X_{it}' \beta + \alpha_i + \nu_t
$$

where on the left-hand side of the equation you observe *counts* of crimes in and around lot $i$ in month $t$. On the right-hand side we have a treatment-control term $T_{it}$, a pre-post construction term $P_{it}$, and the interaction of the constituent terms (i.e., $T_{it} \times P_{it}$) which is estimating the difference-in-differences coefficient. In several papers (see, e.g., [Kondo et al. 2016](https://www.fs.usda.gov/nrs/pubs/jrnl/2015/nrs_2015_kondo_004.pdf)) the variables representing treatment-control and pre-post will often be $i$- and $t$-subscripted. I assume within each "group" (i.e., city section) where the matching procedure was conducted they assigned the start date for treated lots to their matched counterparts. This is permissible, but I assume the start dates varied only by city section, which would make the constituent terms vary by lot and period. In the end, the interaction of these two terms should be your principal focus. Often a single treatment dummy $D_{it}$ is preferred, which is equal to 1 if the lot was greened *and* is in the periods after the treatment's start date. The parameters $\alpha_i$ and $\nu_t$ denote fixed effects for lots and months, respectively.  I assume you're observing incidents of crime over months $t$, though you could aggregate this up to quarterly or even yearly time units. The variable $X_{it}$ is a vector of time-varying control variables.

You may also want to consider treating each $i$ as *random* and including the pre-period mean outcome (e.g., $M_i$) on the right-hand side. It's common in the greening literature to specify a group-level random effects parameter, where $\alpha_i$ is measuring nearby lot groupings. I am somewhat partial to this approach, especially when working with matched sets. However, the decision to model $\alpha_i$ as fixed or random is sometimes a content-area matter. [Locke et al. 2017](https://www.fs.usda.gov/nrs/pubs/jrnl/2017/nrs_2017_locke_001.pdf) assessed the effects of street tree planting on crime in New Haven, Connecticut. Their unit of analysis was the block face, which they also modeled as fixed. Just to be clear, if you're modeling your units (e.g., lots, block faces, street segments, etc.) as "fixed" then I wouldn't recommend adjusting for the mean outcome in the pre-period. Note how the mean crime outcome term, $M_i$, is $i$-subscripted; it's *time invariant*. The inclusion of $\alpha_i$ adjusts for all time constant factors, including the pre-greening differences in crime between treated and untreated lots. The *level differences* across groups shouldn't concern you, but their trends *over time* in the pre-greening epoch should. They should be relatively stable before the community-greening initiative commences.

Now suppose you want to run separate models by city section. If you suspect heterogeneity across geographic regions, then this is one way to proceed. The interaction you propose isn't appropriate, especially with a data frame with duplicate control lots. [Branas et al. 2011](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3224254/) exploited the heterogeneity of various greening effects across different areas of Philadelphia, Pennsylvania by running separate difference-in-differences models, *by city section*. I don't see why you couldn't do the same, though if this is at the neighborhood level it could be limiting in terms of the number of available treatment-control lots.

Running separate models by city section will help avoid the issue of duplicative controls. If the `subclass` variable has many levels, then a neat trick is to group by `subclass` and then estimate a separate Poisson model within each group. Here is some example code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df |> 
  group_by(subclass) |> 
  nest() |> 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~glm(crimes ~ treatment*period, family = "poisson", data = .)))
```

This should result in a data frame with 75 rows and 3 columns. The first column is a subclass identifier, one for each subclass. The second column holds the raw data within each subclass. The third column stores the Poisson estimates. This is just a fancy way of housing all your regression results.

And lastly, I wouldn't recommend limiting your data to the Spring and Summer. If you're concerned about cyclical patterns in the raw data, then methods exist to help you model this. If you're worried about the predominance of zeros in colder climate, then there are adjustments for this as well. Don't throw away data unnecessarily.

Comment: I was able to get the 75x3 data frame like you said, however none of the Poisson estimates include p-values to show significance. I like the idea of doing a city wide regression and then individual district regressions. My confusion is how to run a city wide (or even district wide) regression with matched control lots. The method you give results in individual DiD estimates for each treatment lot. I do not understand how to aggregate these individual results into one DiD estimate. How do I use the subclass matching to perform a regression on the entire city?

Comment: To clarify my comment above, I am struggling to run a regression for a the entire city, or even just a district, such that I have the 1:4 match ratio as you mention. I am familiar with these papers (and cite them in my own), but I don't understand how they got a single DiD estimate for the city when using matched lots. If I ran the regression as I did in my question, but matched control lots to treated lots without replacement (to do away with the duplicate control lots - so no untreated lot is used as a control for more than one treated lot), would the results then be correct?

Comment: First, store the results (e.g., `df <- ...`). Next, extract each model summary manually using the following code: `summary(df[['model']][[1]])`. This will produce the summary output that you're used to seeing. Repeat this for different values of subclass (i.e., `1`, `2`, `3`, etc.).

Comment: Second, why does running one equation with all matched lots seem inappropriate? In the referenced research, the authors typically match untreated lots to treated lots in the same city section. Once the matching process is complete, then run your model. If what I've recommended doesn't make sense, then please follow-up here. I will adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: Running one equation with all matched lots seems very appropriate and is what I want to do, I just don't understand how. I may not be explaining my problem clearly. Using your method makes sense, however I can only seem to get the estimate on a per-treated-lot basis, not a cumulative estimate. I do not understand how to match the controls then run one equation with all matched lots. I can only seem to get 75 estimates, one for each treated lot, but no aggregate estimate for the city after matching via subclass. Unless, is `(df[['model']][[1]])` not treated lot 1, but the aggregate estimate?

Comment: I think I understand your confusion a little better now. The variable `subclass` should be used to run *separate* regressions by geography. Here is an example from New York City. I might use `subclass` to index street segments in different geographic boroughs. The code I recommended would give me a *separate* DiD estimate by borough (i.e., Brooklyn, Queens, etc.). I would report the five coefficients in tabular form separately. I would only recommend this approach if this was a large-scale citywide greening project.

Comment: In practice, we usually run the regression on the matched sample. If this was truly a citywide greening initiative, then I recommend conducting a separate matching process in each region of the city. For example, you might want to ensure 3 control lots per treated lot for each section. Once you have the matched data frame, then run one model to obtain the aggregate DiD estimate. The triple interaction term you're proposing is not going to do the 'pairing' as you suggested. You need to pre-process your data before running your model.

Comment: You are again correct, that is the problem I am having. I actually have a variable for each lot for its census tract, neighborhood, and district. So I could run each district separately, then the city as a whole. You got right to the hear oft my problem: I do not know how to run one model with matching to obtain the aggregate DiD estimate. I thought my `subclass` that paired one treated lot to acceptable control lots was "matching". I will look more into how to preprocess my data for matching.

Comment: I think you're referring to "matching" in the more general sense. To be clear, I don't see any reason why you can't group by your neighborhoods and randomly select control lots, though this is probably the least valid approach in my estimation. There are many different semi-parametric and non-parametric matching methods. I would familiarize yourself with the [MatchIt](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/MatchIt.pdf) package in R.